# Quais as possíveis causas do erro "Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server aborted" e como corrigir?

Tags: php, apache, servidor

Segundo algumas repostas no SO, como [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888020/connection-reset-by-peer-fastcgi-comm-with-server-aborted-read-failed) e [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312621/fastcgi-comm-with-server-aborted-read-failed), parece que o erro ocorre por que acaba o `max_execution_time`, mas não ficou claro pra mim quais são as possíveis causas e como resolver este erro.

O erro é basicamente este:

> (104)Connection reset by peer: [client XXXX] FastCGI: comm with server
>   "/home/site/www/php7.0.external" aborted: read failed, referer:
>   https://www.google.com/

O que pode provocar este erro, e como resolver as causas possíveis?

Comment: Aparentemente a execução do script está sendo prolongada, mas desse modo não há como ter certeza. Pode ser um loop infinito, um _bug_, escassez de recurso no sistema ou ainda outra coisa. É possível exibir um pouco mais de informação?

Comment: Esse erro é genérico e pode variar conforme a situação: 1. A resposta da execução é muito grande e por conta disso a conexão é interrompida; 2. Problema na network do servidor (ou limitação), que faz com que a conexão seja interrompida em tempo X de execução; 3. Existe algum proxy no servidor que interrompe a conexão durante a execução; 4. Limitação de memória; 5. Consumo intenso da CPU; 6. Configuração do **-idle-timeout** no FastCGI; Em todo caso não tem como dizer como resolver, terá que investigar o que está causando o timeout conforme as possíveis causas.